# I have 2 identically structured beans and 2 identically structured getter statements, yet only one works

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, constructor, javabeans

I have two beans that are structured exactly the same.  I pull both those beans into the same java class the exact same way.  Yet only one of them has a problem.

Here is the error when I try to build it:

> cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : constructor BalanceBean(java.lang.String)
>   location: class HWpackage.BalanceBean

Here is the working bean, UserBean2

```
package HWpackage;

public class UserBean2 {
  private String id;

  public UserBean2(String id) {
    setUsername(id);
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return(id);
  }

  public void setUsername(String id) {
    if (!isMissing(id)) {
      this.id = id;
    }
  }

  private boolean isMissing(String value) {
    return((value == null) || (value.trim().equals("")));
  }
}
```

And here is the working getter statements:

```
  UserBean2 userBean2 = (UserBean2)session.getAttribute("userBean2");
  String un = request.getParameter("id");
  userBean2 = new UserBean2(un);
  session.setAttribute("userBean2", userBean2);
```

Now compare that to the non-working code.

BalanceBean:

```
package HWpackage;

public class BalanceBean {
  private String balance, id;

  public BalanceBean (String balance, String id) {
    setBalance(balance);
    setID(id);
  }

  public String getBalance() {
    return(balance);
  }

  public void setBalance(String balance)
  {
      this.balance = balance;
  }

  public String getID() {
    return(id);
  }

  public void setID(String id)
  {
      this.id = id;
  }
}
```

And its getter statements:

```
BalanceBean balanceBean = (BalanceBean)session.getAttribute("balanceBean");
String balance = request.getParameter("balance");
balanceBean = new BalanceBean(balance);
session.setAttribute("balanceBean", balanceBean);
```

For what ever reason, the BalanceBean in the line: balanceBean = new BalanceBean(balance);
is causing all the problems.

Can someone please tell me why?

**UPDATED:**
OK, if I change my BalanceBean to:

```
package HWpackage;

public class BalanceBean {
  private String balance, id;

  public BalanceBean (String balance) {
    setBalance(balance);        
  }

  public String getBalance() {
    return(balance);
  }

  public void setBalance(String balance)
  {
      this.balance = balance;
  }

  public String getID() {
    return(id);
  }

  public void setID(String id)
  {
      this.id = id;
  }
}
```

How do I add back my String id?

Comment: I didn't realize I couldn't just put everything I needed in there. So am I able to have both the balance and id in the same bean? And if so, how do I set that up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not identical, and the error is telling you exactly what is wrong:

```
cannot find symbol symbol : constructor BalanceBean(java.lang.String)
```

You do not have a constructor in BalanceBean that takes a `String` as the only argument.

You have:

```
public BalanceBean (String balance, String id)
```

And are trying to call:

```
balanceBean = new BalanceBean(balance);
```

**Edit:** If you want to add a second constructor, you are more than able to:

```
public BalanceBean (String balance) {
    setBalance(balance);
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize I couldn't just put everything I needed in there.  So am I able to have both the balance and id in the same bean?  And if so, how do I set that up?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking. You can do whatever you want. Currently you're trying to call a constructor that doesn't exist. Your constructor requires 2 strings and you're giving it one. Create a second constructor that only takes one String if you want, just like in your other bean (see my edited answer above).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I updated my question if you could help me with that I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @Turk, you seem to not understand the basics of how methods or constructors work. I'm not sure how to help in this situation other than to say you need to start with a basic programming tutorial. Your first constructor was fine if you wanted to supply 2 strings (balance and id), but you weren't doing that. Now you've changed it to only take a single argument.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you for your help, I think I got it.  I looked up some information on constructors and I believe I found my answer.  You've been a great help!

Answer (score 1):

BalanceBean has a two arg constructor. `public BalanceBean (String balance, String id)`. You are passing only one argument `new BalanceBean(balance)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the BalanceBean class constructors, it appears you haven't define a constructor with only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor BalanceBeam(String, String) expects 2 parameters, and you're only providing it one parameter.  Therefore a new constructor of type BalanceBeam(String) is needed